# Pagination with HTML Table

Tags: php, laravel

In the table below, i put every student under the teacher that you belong in the table. Now, i want to rather paginate the students being shown under the table. So if 1st tab has 10 students, i could paginate to 5.

Currently, my code doesn't do what i want to achieve.  How do i achieve this?

PS: I know how the syntax would be if i wanted to paginate teachers like `teachers->links()`

**Controller**

```
$teacher = Teacher::where('branch_id', Auth::user()->branch_id);
return view('create',compact('teachers));
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav-tabs-custom" id="tabs">
    <ul  id="myUL" class="nav nav-tabs">
        @foreach($teachers as $teacher)
            <li ><a href="#tab_{{ $teacher->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$teacher->name!!}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        @foreach($teachers as $key => teacher)
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_{{ $teacher->id }}">
                <table class="table" id="tables">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th colspan="5"></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($teacher->students as $std)
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>{{$std->name }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {{$teacher->stduents->links()}}
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DestinatioN, you would edit this and think its a possible duplicate? I see no point of duplicating this question :)

Comment: Sry misread you question. Probably this should be helpful https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-paginate-relations-in-laravel

Comment: @DestinatioN, kindly remove the duplicate tag

Comment: What if just using [Laravel pagination features](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have a couple syntax errors, i imagine their typo's but just in case: `$teacher` in controller should be plural, And  `@foreach($teachers as $key => teacher)` value should be `$teacher` and `{{$teacher->stduents->links()}}` should probably be students

In your controller you could do:

```
$teachers = Teacher::where('branch_id', Auth::user()->branch_id)->get();

foreach ($teachers as $teacher) {
    $students = $teacher->students()->paginate(5);
}

return view('index', compact('teachers', 'students'));
```

And in your view:

```
        @foreach($students as $std)
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>{{$std->name }}</td>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{{$students->links()}}
```

This should also work. In your **Teacher** model:

```
public function paginateStd()
{
    return $this->students()->paginate(5);
}
```

And in your view:

```
    @foreach($teacher->paginateStd() as $std)
       <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td>{{$std->name }}</td>
           <td></td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{{$teacher->paginateStd()->links()}}
```

Comment: In the view, `@foreach($students as $std)` doesn't show anything in the table.. I did `return $students` in the controller and i did return the the valid Json. you know why this could be happening in the view/

Comment: Do you mean by valid Json it contained the students? You could dd($students) in the controller after the foreach loop to verify if there is data

Comment: Okay when i `dd($stduents)` or return $students after the forloop, no data is showing

Comment: then your relationship $teacher->students() doesn't bring back results..have you set it up properly? And you could dd($teachers) in your controler to verify if that has data.

Comment: yes, for teachers, i get results... both of them have many to many relationship

Comment: I have 3 teachers. I am now seeing that, it is only returning the students for the last teacher amongst the 3

Comment: So the relationship is working? And do the other teachers even have students?

Comment: Yes other teachers have students but it is not showing theirs. the relationship should be working because i have been using it in other models